# Maven build plugin for a Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

We have a spring boot application which generates Linux distribution tar.gz file when done with Maven build. We want to generate a Windows distribution file (like .zip) when done with Maven build.

We are using a Spring Boot container (wrapped with our company's own container) which takes the following by default:

```
<descriptors>
   <descriptorRef>distribution-unix</descriptorRef>
</descriptors>
```

So the *tar.gz file gets generated on doing Maven build. We need to write our own configurations to generate a *.zip file for Windows OS.

I'd be interested in any examples where I can learn how to configure this.

In main POM:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the distribution module POM:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.xxxx.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>container-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <embeddedLaunchScriptRuntimeProperties>
                        <JAVA_OPTS>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m</JAVA_OPTS>
                        <RUN_ARGS>--spring.profiles.active=${active_profiles}</RUN_ARGS>
                        <PATH>${java_home}/bin:$PATH</PATH>
                    </embeddedLaunchScriptRuntimeProperties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```